# Unable to use Randoop testjar

Tags: java, randoop

I have a folder containing `randoop-all-4.3.0.jar` and `project.jar`. I want to test the entire jar as a whole using `java -classpath randoop-all-4.3.0.jar randoop.main.Main gentests --testjar=project.jar` but I am getting the following error:

```
Randoop for Java version 4.3.0.

AppInterface was read from project.jar but was not found on classpath.  Ensure that project.jar is on the classpath.  Classpath:
randoop-all-4.3.0.jar
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your command `java -classpath randoop-all-4.3.0.jar` provided a classpath that  contains Randoop but does not contain your code.

As described in the ["Running Randoop" section](https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/#running_randoop) of the Randoop manual, a typical invocation is

```
    java -classpath myclasspath:${RANDOOP_JAR} randoop.main.Main ...
```

In your case, that would be

```
    java -classpath project.jar:${RANDOOP_JAR} randoop.main.Main ...
```